# how do they used to enter machine code directly in olden days?

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science

I read in this article [1GL: First Generation Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language) that people used to enter machine instructions directly.

I want to see some pictures of their keyboard & monitor. Did they directly enter these instructions into memory? of they were directly send to CPU? at what frequency it used to operate? I want to read more about those computers and programming them.

kindly post some good references. If you have seen or programmed one of those machines please tell me the story.

Comment: See my previous answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805491/how-can-you-tell-a-normal-person-about-first-program/2805586#2805586.

Comment: Keyboards? Monitors? Don't think so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting a short remark with lots of follow on questions from OP into a long answer:)

I entered bootstrap loaders through switches on Data General Novas (16 bit machines) in 1969. For an Packard Bell 250 that I toyed with in 1967, there was a Flexowriter equipped with a paper tape reader, to load the program in the delay line memory.

For the Nova, there was one row of 16 toggle switches, and a half dozen other switches whose functions were "Set Memory Address", "Deposit Word and advance memory address", "Single Step" (we used that a lot for early debugging!), "Run" and "Halt", IIRC.

The Nova initially had 4096 words of 16 bit memory, the worlds ugliest RISC instruction set with 4 16 bit registers (stack? who needs a stinking stack?), and something like a 1 microsecond memory cycle time (instructions took several cycles). The machine had a "serial port" that connected to an ASR33 Teletype (10 characters per second), and we splurged for a high-speed paper tape reader and punch.

It initially came as bare hardware, with a paper tape containing a two-pass assembler that read source from, well, the paper tape reader.  We initially wrote assembly code source onto punched paper tape directly with the ASR33 Teletype; this including "rubout" punches to wipe out characters that were wrong. Editing was incredibly painful. A cohort wrote a bad editor as the very first thing, that read a paper tape into a buffer in the computer, let us find lines, delete lines, and insert lines

My first job was to implement a Kemeny&Kurtz style BASIC interpreter on this. Two years later we added 4K more words and 100K word head-per-track disk, and I built a multiuser timesharing system on it, both written with that ugly editor. Ugh. I built OSes on various machines for the next 20 years.

The Linkers/Loaders books talks about "linkers", that combine multiple object files. Our assembler didn't bother; it produced, for your assembly code, a directly loadable binary paper tape. That tape was designed to be loaded by a tiny program that was entered, well, back to the opening of this discussion, a 30-odd word bootstrap program entered from the front panel. After each program run (usually ending in "crash") we usually had to re-enter that boot loader; we got pretty good at since we often did it several times a day.

Regarding coding forms: people did write code on such forms, and then somebody else often "punched" them onto paper tape. The purpose of the form was to make sure the person doing the punching put stuff  where you said, and made you the coder rather more careful about pensmanship in what you coded (I still print block capitals pretty neatly). It didn't take us long to realize that you could code free-form, and after that I did most of my coding on graph paper with faint lines so it looked sort of neat before typing it into the editor.

You couldn't effectively hack online with the text editor; it didn't hold enough text for you to cut and paste arbitrarily, so you had to edit in one pass and make changes from beginning to end in order.  Consequently, newspaper style editing on paper as you coded intially was far more effective. After first coding, we'd run program listings and then write on those listing what edits we wanted to make, before we went and made them. Screen editors with giant buffers are much nicer!

The Packard Bell 250 was similar to the Data General machine, except it (remarkably) had a built-in loader program and came with an editor. Because it had a delay line memory (think of this as sometihing like a disk track), you place instructions along the delay line such that when the previous instrution was done, the next instruction just so happened to be coming under the "heads". Talk about painful to optimize... It had one great property; when you got frustrated, you could just whack the CPU and the mechanical shock would make the machine forget everything. Very satisyfing for a moment.  Then you had to start over.

Ah, to be associated with "ye olden days".

Comment: Was it at all practical to cut, splice, or overtype on a paper tape, or did all editing have to be done on-line?

Comment: All the editing on the PB250 was done with a Flexowriter, that wrote punched paper tape as typed.  BACKSPACE/RUBOUT backed up one row of holes, and punched them all (xFF) thus "RUBOUT" character code in ASCII.  On the DG Nova, we had a teletype, a really terrible text editor my boss wrote, a high speed paper tape punch, and desperation manual hole puncher you could use to edit individual places on the tape that didn't already have holes (mostly used to make rubout characters).   What-you-see-is-what-you-punch; who could ask for anything more?

Comment: Suppose you had a tape that was almost perfect, except that you wanted to insert a line of text somewhere and remove a line from somewhere else.  Would you somehow direct the machine to copy data from the source tape to the destination until you reached the spot you wanted the insertion, then type in the new data, then copy until you reached the delete point, and then copy everything from there to the end?  Or would you type up a tape with some editing instructions (a small enough number to fit in RAM!) and feed that into the computer followed by the source tape, or what?

Comment: Well, we had a text editor that would collect a buffer of text of several hundred lines.  Read the tape into the buffer, edit lines, spit out new tape.   Really desperate: mylar patches enabling you slice the tape, patch in new tape segments.   You actually get good at this after awhile, but its a skill I'm glad I lost.

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_panel

> A **front panel** was used on early electronic computers to display and allow the alteration of the state of the machine's internal registers and memory. The front panel usually consisted of arrays of *indicator lamps*, *toggle switches*, and *push buttons* mounted on a sheet metal face plate.

Answer (score 3):

The oldest computer I've programmed is the (not very ancient) PDP-8. To get it to a point where you can start loading from paper tape, punched cards or a disk, you need to enter some bootstrap code from the front panel. You start by setting an address where you want to load code, then you can enter each word via the switches on the front, finishing each word by flipping the (spring-loaded) LOAD switch (this will then increment the word pointer, so you can simply enter the next word).

Once you've loaded your bootstrap, you then load the start address into the address register and flip the RUN switch.

Comment: I did this on Data General Novas (16 bit machines) in 1969.   For an Packard Bell 250 that I toyed with in 1967, there was a Flexowriter equipped with a paper tape reader, to load the program in the delay line memory.

Comment: Wow! I'm lucky. I'm talking to guys how programmed main frames and mini computers.I've few questions for you guys.FYi, the first computer I programmed was Pentium-4. I'm still programming on it :(

Comment: @Vatine: By 'word' do you mean 16bits? Was there a switch for each bit position? so for entering a word you need to set these 16 switches and then flip the LOAD switch? How exactly was it?

Comment: @Ira Baxter & @Vatine: 1. So how do you use to tell the specifications of those computers? How many KBs of RAM? Whats processor speed & what else you used to specify? 2. Do these computers used to have Operating Systems? If they had, which OSes they used to run? 3. Wiki says that first compiler came in 1954 (for FORTRAN). I want to know if these compilers ran without OS loaded? where do you write these programs? ( I guess no text editors then?)

Comment: 4. http://www.flexus.com/ftp/cobolforms95.xls shows COBOL form. I've seen in a documentary that the program is written in specific boxes. Why is it so?
5. I read in "Linkers & Loaders" book that programs are linked by hand. when compiler is running in the computer. How come they linked it using pen & paper?

Comment: @Claws: see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Just to divert slightly from the mainframe approach...

My first experience of low-level was on the Sinclair ZX-81. This had a variant of BASIC built in, but you could program "easily" in Z-80 machine code by this means:

- Add a REM (comment) statement to a BASIC program. Fill this with characters in order to "reserve" some memory for your code.
- Look up the machinecode opcodes in a list, and hand-assemble the machine code as byte values
- Enter the byte values into the BASIC program as DATA statements, with a short loop that reads each byte value in turn and POKEs it into the memory holding the "text" of the REM statement.
- Jump to the entry-point address of the machine code.

After that I moved up to the BBC micro, which had an awesome 6502 Assembler built directly into its BBC Basic, so it was no longer necessary to go to such extreme lengths to enter the machine code directly.

Ah, the good old days... :-)

Comment: is that the one where you can also use audiotape as media storage?
it has been a long time since I used it :-)

Comment: @aaa: Yes. And if there was an error in reading the tape you had to try chnaging the volume slightly, rewinding to the beginning, and trying again. Ah, the bad old days :-)

Comment: changing the *volume*? You could actually run your programs louder in those days? :)

Answer (score 2):

Early 80s, I was a kid and my family was fortunate enough to own a personal computer--  An "Apple II".  Like many programmers, I got started as a kid because I wanted to create my own games.  There was a BASIC language interpreter built in called Applesoft BASIC, but it was too slow to do any reasonable animation.  The commercial games, at least I was told, were all written in assembly language.  So there began the quest... to learn assembly language... which first meant learning MACHINE language... (the direct entry of hexidecimal numbers rather than three letter text codes representing microprocessor instructions).

The Apple II used the 6502 microprocessor.  The first thing you had to learn was the memory map, which was the range and purpose of each section of memory (RAM and ROM).  Here is a link to the memory map of the Apple ][e: [link text](http://apple.bikibird.com/appleIIeMemoryMap.html)

The black numbers on the left margin are the memory locations.  Note it goes from $0000 to $FFFF.  The 6502 could only address 16^4 = 65536 or 64k of memory.  You can see the RAM ended at $BFFF.  The $C000-$CFFF range would access any peripheral cards you placed in the computer.  For example the disk drive controller would go in slot #6 and would show up at $C600.  I felt really cool as a kid that I could reboot the system by typing `$C600G` which would execute ("G" for "Go") the disk controller re-boot routine in ROM.  The space from $E000 to $FFFF was originally just ROM, but the Apple ][e ("e" for "enhanced") let you switch back and forth ("bank switch") and access that extra 8k of memory.

Do you see the graphics and text areas of the memory map?  That how you would display to the screen.  In those days (pre-GUI) there was a "text" mode where programs in ROM would continually scan memory between $0400-$0800 (= 4*16*16 = 1024 byte locations each corresponding to a place on the screen).  It would take whatever ASCII byte was stuffed there and turn it into a character on your monitor.  Here is the 6502 instruction set which among other things allowed you to move bytes around: [6502 Instruction Set](http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/6502_instruction_set.html)

And to put it into context, here is a sub-routine from ROM which adds to floating point numbers called FADD: (full floating point routine collection [here](http://www.6502.org/source/floats/wozfp3.txt))

```
F46E: A5 F4     FADD      LDA  X2
F470: C5 F8               CMP  X1       COMPARE EXP1 WITH EXP2.
F472: D0 F7               BNE  SWPALGN  IF #,SWAP ADDENDS OR ALIGN MANTS.
F474: 20 25 F4            JSR  ADD      ADD ALIGNED MANTISSAS.
F477: 50 EA     ADDEND    BVC  NORM     NO OVERFLOW, NORMALIZE RESULT.
F479: 70 05               BVS  RTLOG    OV: SHIFT M1 RIGHT, CARRY INTO SIGN
F47B: 90 C4     ALGNSWP   BCC  SWAP     SWAP IF CARRY CLEAR,
                *       ELSE SHIFT RIGHT ARITH.
F47D: A5 F9     RTAR      LDA  M1       SIGN OF MANT1 INTO CARRY FOR
F47F: 0A                  ASL           RIGHT ARITH SHIFT.
F480: E6 F8     RTLOG     INC  X1       INCR X1 TO ADJUST FOR RIGHT SHIFT
F482: F0 75               BEQ  OVFL     EXP1 OUT OF RANGE.
F484: A2 FA     RTLOG1    LDX  #$FA     INDEX FOR 6:BYTE RIGHT SHIFT.
F486: 76 FF     ROR1      ROR  E+3,X
F488: E8                  INX           NEXT BYTE OF SHIFT.
F489: D0 FB               BNE  ROR1     LOOP UNTIL DONE.
F48B: 60                  RTS           RETURN.
```

Looking at the routine, the first four hex numbers before the colon are the memory address.  So if you wanted to run the FADD routine directly, you'd type `F46EG` (again, the "G" for "go).

The next two hex numbers, $A5 and $F4, are the instruction codes.  If you look at the handy instruction set chart, you see that $A5 means "LDA" or load the accumulator.  The accumulator was one of the three memory locations (each one byte) on the 6502 processor for you to do computations with (that was nice of them, eh?).  The $A5 version of the LDA command meant that the memory location to load was from the so called "zero page" or first $FF bytes of RAM which were mostly reserved for system use (there were a few bytes free for programmer use.  Again, that was so nice of them.)  The $F4 is the memory location whose contents (one byte) will be transferred to the accumulator.  The next line has the instruction $C5 or "CMP" command, again the zero page version, which then compares the contents of the accumulator with memory location $F8.  So that's the lowest level known as "MACHINE LANGUAGE" and yes, we'd sometimes type in little programs or mess with memory for debugging purposes.

The next few columns are more readable; you see the actual "LDA" and "CMP" commands and variables X1 and X2 which represent those memory locations.  You also see Woz's comments on what the code is doing (comparing the exponents of two floats).  This is known as "Assembly Language" and is what was actually typed in.  After you typed it in your assembler would compile the byte codes.

Well, I never did manage to create a reasonable game on the Apple ][ but I sure did learn a lot about programming trying!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you go back far enough code was entered through punch cards.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming_in_the_punch_card_era

Answer (score 1):

from 19th century and on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card

Comment: Sadly I remember programming with punch cards.  Still remember how critical it was to number your stack. Learned the lesson the hard way dropping a stack of cards I didn't number beforehand.

Comment: Ye old trick was to run a marker across the top of the card deck diagnonally.  Then if you dropped the deck, and put them back in box, you could which cards were out of place.  Of course, you couldn't edit the code a lot and still use this trick, because the replacement punchcards weren't marked.

Answer (score 1):

We still have similar devices (8085 kits, for example) in microprocessor labs in universities - they usually have a hex keypad that you use to enter the machine code into some specified location in RAM, and then you press another key to start execution. Pretty much every computer since the 1950s has had separate RAM, so no, the instructions never go directly into the CPU.

You may want to look at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_System_Development_Kit) for some images of these training kits.

Answer (score 0):

The first computer I programmed was an [IBM 1620](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1620). I used punched cards, as mentioned previously. A similar machine is the [IBM 1401](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_1401). You can read about the "bootstrap" routine for the 1620 and about "Booting" the 1401. A bootstrap, or booting, is like a PC BIOS in that they are the first code the machine executes to get other code to execute. The bootstap for those machines would normally read machine code from a punched card or punched cards. After booting a compiler or assembler could be used. I was in High School and lerned my first programming language, Fortan, using the 1620.